# Spring Boot Database connection Table not found

Tags: java, spring-boot, jdbctemplate

I am developing my first Spring Boot Application and i am facing a problem with the database connection.

I am Using maven 4.0.0 and i want to operate on the Database(H2) using JdbcTemplate. I tried to configure the database access in the application.properties file, which i created in the resources folder.

This is my pom.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>obudb2</groupId>
    <artifactId>boudb2</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId> <!--todo: change to starter-jdbc!-->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.60</version>

        </dependency>

    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I created my h2 database with following properties:
[image]

I access the database within the following dao class:

```
@Repository
public class CustomerDaoImpl implements CustomerDao {


    private String selectAllStatement = "select * from Customer";

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Override
    public List<Customer> findAllCustomers() {
        return jdbcTemplate.query(selectAllStatement,new CustomerMapper());
    }

}
```

and my application.properties file looks as follows:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:sourceDb
spring.datasource.username=admin
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
```

i am getting the following error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: StatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [select * from CUSTOMER]; nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Tabelle CUSTOMER nicht gefunden
Table CUSTOMER not found; SQL statement:
select * from CUSTOMER [42S02-60]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:234) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:72) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.translateException(JdbcTemplate.java:1402) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:388) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:446) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:456) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at dao.CustomerDaoImpl.findAllCustomers(CustomerDaoImpl.java:25) ~[classes/:na]
    at dao.CustomerDaoImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$c0781898.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) ~[spring-core-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:747) ~[spring-aop-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-tx-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:689) ~[spring-aop-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
    at dao.CustomerDaoImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$da434872.findAllCustomers(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at service.TransferService.transferData(TransferService.java:26) ~[classes/:na]
    at main.ObuDbTransfer.run(ObuDbTransfer.java:34) [classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:797) ~[spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
```

I think there might be a problem with the datasource. Maybe it is not linked correctly, but for my understanding spring boot should automatically generate a datasource out of the application.properties file. So i am out of ideas what could go wrong here.
I hope somebody could point out what i am missing out here.

Comment: spring.datasource.password=

Comment: i added spring.datasource.password=
to my propierties file, but i am stil facing the issue.

Comment: You should add `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect` as well.

Comment: @hiaslosch17 just a question are you sure that the table really exist ?

Comment: it seems like everytime i close the h2 console all tables get deleted. I am facing this for the first time, before i tried it with different db names in a different order and there this didnt happen.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't accidently activated a `create-drop` setting?

Comment: yeah i am sure i didnt activate such a setting. When i log into the console i can create a table and insert rows as usual, but when i terminate the connection and reconnect all tables are gone.

Comment: i created now a different database under the link: **jdbc:h2:file:C:\Users\Matthias\db\sourceDb**
here the tables are not deleted when i am disconnecting from the database. 

Allthough i have the same issue as addressed in my question: the table customer can still not be found

Comment: Try this. spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE

Answer (score 0):

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
add this entry in your application.properties file.

Comment: Please, put an explanation with your answer for the sake of increased understandability of your answer.